# I get two different answers on simple equation. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the equation: $-x^2 = -2x(3x+1)$ I can either multiply it out on the right side and get a $-6x^2-2x$ or just divide both sides by $-2x$. However, when divide out both sides, I just get one answer: $-2/5$. When I multiply it out, I get two answers: $-2/5$ and $0$.

What is wrong with dividing both sides by $-2x$??

Comment: There is one situation where division is forbidden. This is why you lose a solution.

Comment: Is there a specific rule that forbids me from making these types of error that I can adhere to?

Comment: A rule, I don't know. A high sense of auto-criticism may help: before making any operation, ask yourself "Can I do this?". Auto-criticism can be substituted by a friend that reads and checks your work. I had a classmate at university that never missed a flaw or a missing gap in my writing, and was not reluctant to tell me about these. She was a real daemon, but she was really helpful

Comment: I believe that the rule is "you cant divide by zero"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you divide by $-2x$ you are implicitly assuming $x\neq0$ which you don't know for sure and thus remove that solution.

---

Note that when you divide by a non-zero value the equation still holds on each side whereas division by zero will create undefined expressions. For example, $\frac{1}{0}$ doesn't compute to any known value where there are Math SE questions on this topic if you need a reference.

Consider if the equation was $2x=x$ where if I divide by $x$, I then get $1=2$ which is a problem as that isn't true and the reason why that division isn't allowed is because the *only* solution is $x=0$.

Comment: Then why are we allowed to divide anything by x and still get the right answer?

Comment: @Joe the point is that you aren't. You could get the wrong answer as evidenced in your post.

Comment: It’s not exactly that we’re “allowed” to do or not to do this or that in mathematics. Rather, it’s that some operations are valid, and some aren’t. Dividing by a quantity that may be zero is not valid.

Comment: Couldn't all x's technically be zero, unless otherwise defined? Yet when we solve equations, why is it commonly taught to divide both sides by x?

Comment: @Joe, whenever one is going to divide an expression to solve an equation, there is a check to make sure that the division isn't by zero. Generally this is a rather straightforward check.

Comment: @Joe: In defence to teachers who may divide by $x$, in a basic elementary level algebra class, children are unaware of even working with equations. Certain rules are bent to make it seem *easier*. Kids, as you know, don't like things with too many rules. But rules do exist and for good reason. So, it's always good practice to verify $x \neq 0$ before dividing with it.

Comment: @Joe, I think it may be worth revisiting the concepts of domains and ranges and how they affect which operations you can perform. I remember learning about them in high school answered many questions like this.

Comment: Ok! Thank you guys so much for the help =D